# What Siemens part can I replace this Lovato part with?

Tags: circuit-breaker

**Original part:**
Lovato Circuit Breaker -- 10A, 2-Pole, C-curve -- https://www.solutionsdirectonline.com/lovato-miniature-circuit-breaker-10a-2-poles-p1mb2pc10

Official page: https://www.lovatoelectric.com/-MINIATURE-CIRCUIT-BREAKER,-2P--10KA.-2-MODULES,-CHARACTERISTIC-C,-10A/P1MB2PC10/snp

**Proposed replacement:** https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/WW/Catalog/Product/?mlfb=3RV2011-0DA20-Z+W97 -- datasheet for this was a bit confusing until I confirmed that "breaking capacity" is the same as "interrupt rating"

**Discredited replacements:**
Residual current operated circuit breaker, 2-pole, type A, In: 16 A, 10 mA, Un AC: 230 V: https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/WW/Catalog/Product/5SV3111-6

Or maybe: 10A MCB 2 Pole Type C 6kA
https://www.lcautomation.com/Store/Category/493/Product/5SY6210-7.aspx

**Edits**
EDIT 1: This is in an industrial setting in the USA. Circuit includes motors.

EDIT 2: Was a bit confused because I interpreted "Type A" to mean "Curve Type A" but many readings on the subject don't mention Curve Type A in readings on the subject ([example](https://www.c3controls.com/white-paper/understanding-trip-curves/)). Wondering what I'm missing.

[This reading](https://library.e.abb.com/public/06f0ad870bda4dd7b47f71699d9a5000/ABB-63_WPO_BreakerCoordination-Final.pdf) does talk about the A Curve as a "main breaker" curve.

EDIT 3: Added third proposed replacement.

Comment: In which use, residential, commercial, industrial? What load is it protecting, motors, fluorescent lighs? Which country is this so people familiar with local laws, regulations and codes can answer it better?

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Comment: Legally in the EU? Yes. US? No idea. But it will not tolerate inrush as you might be accustomed to with regular C type.

Comment: Is the UL1077 listing of the original important?  Is the 10kA interrupting rating important?   The proposed replacements are 6kA and not listed.

Comment: Motor will have type C for a reason. Expect frequent nuisance trips while starting a motor off a type A.

Answer (score 2):

The original part is listed to UL 1077, which is for supplementary protection.  This is the type usually seen in packaged equipment controls.  (As opposed to the breakers used in panelboards, switchboards, etc. which would be listed to UL 489.)

The original part is also rated for 10kA interrupting.  If the system (e.g. control panel) this goes into is rated for 10kA, then installing a breaker with a lower interrupting rating (like the 6kA of the proposed products) will reduce the rating of the entire control panel to 6kA.  (Do you know what fault current is available at the mains supply to this equipment?)

The linked "residual current operated" circuit breaker is a totally different type of breaker designed to protect against ground faults.

Comment: Well, shucks... but, sometimes the devil is in the details. I wonder if it will still basically work. Guess I'd need to read up on some kind of compliance standards.

Comment: @DJG "Basically working" is possibly not safe under fault conditions.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's all going to be encased in metal with the total amount of combustible material inside being pretty low... probably not a robust outlook from me.

Comment: @DJG The point of the interrupting rating is this:  If the upstream power system can provide more than 6000A into a short circuit, a 6kA rated breaker *will not open* under a short, and the short circuit will continue until the equipment is destroyed.